# Java Modulo Help

Tags: java, methods, object, modulo

```
public void turnRight() {
        int direction=getDirection();
        if (direction==3)
            direction=0;
        else
            direction++;
        this.setDirection(direction);
```

So I have this method that, when called, increments direction by 1. However, the max value should be 3, so if direction is equal to 3 and the method is called, then it should go back to zero. What I have works, but I'm sure there is a way to do this using the % operator. Can anyone show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
direction++;
direction%=4;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int direction = getDirection();
direction++;  
direction = direction % 4;
```

Comment: I think, in this case, you should consider % 4.

Comment: Max value of direction should be 3, not 2.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I saw at another answer and thought I misunderstood something. sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

public void turnRight(){this.setDirection(getDirection()%4==3?0:getDirection() + 1);}

Comment: I think, in this case, you should consider % 4.

Comment: yep - had to think that through twice.